# Calculate histogram of distances between points in big data set

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

I have big data set, representing 1.2M points in 220 dimensional periodic space (x changes fom (-pi,pi))... (matrix: 1.2M x 220).

I would like to calculate histogram of distances between these points taking into account periodicity. I have written some code in python but still it works quite slow for my test case (I am not even trying to run it on the whole set...).

Can you maybe take a look and help me with some tweaking?

Any suggestions and comments much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np

# 1000x220 test set (-pi,pi)

d=np.random.random((1000, 220))*2*np.pi-np.pi

# calculating theoretical limit on the histogram range, max distance between 
# two points can be pi in each dimension

m=np.zeros(np.shape(d)[1])+np.pi
m_=np.sqrt(np.sum(m**2))
# hist range is from 0 to mm
mm=np.floor(m_)
bins=mm/0.01
m=np.zeros(bins)

# proper calculations

import time
start_time = time.time()

for i in range(np.shape(d)[0]):
        diff=d[:-(i+1),:]-d[i+1:,:]
        diff=np.absolute(diff)
        adiff=diff-np.pi
        diff=np.pi-np.absolute(adiff)
        s=np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', diff,diff))
        m+=np.histogram(s,range=(0,mm),bins=bins)[0]


print time.time() - start_time
```

Comment: have you profiled your code to see where it is spending most of its time?

Comment: Is your actual data integers or floating point?

Comment: @StephenH floating point

Comment: @I.K. thanks for tip, I just played with profiling and it looks like 50% of time my code spends on this line: diff[abs(diff)>np.pi]=2*np.pi-abs(diff[abs(diff)>np.pi])

Comment: In that case, you are computing diff[abs(diff)>np.pi] twice. Try doing it once i.e. hold it in a variable and using that.

Comment: `np.power` seems to eat up quite some time. In a quick test it proved significantly faster to use `diff * diff`. A little faster still is replacing `np.sum(diff*diff,1)` by `np.einsum('ij,ij->i', diff, diff)`.

Comment: thx guys, I updated the code with your suggestions, I also removed abs() -> got from 18s to 8s, still I have problem with dealing with periodicity: diff2[ndiff]=2*np.pi-np.sqrt(diff2[ndiff])

Comment: Also, I'd replace the einsum line and the line above it (diff2) with `np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', diff, diff))`.

Comment: and just using `m += np.histogram(...)[0]` will save a little time too (won't copy the array to `h` first, just adds in place)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will see the most improvement from breaking the main loop to smaller parts by dividing range(...) to a couple of smaller ranges and use the threading module to have a couple of threads run the loop concurrently